# Questions and answers from answers.semanticweb.com

Tags: data-request

answers.semanticweb.com was a QA website a bit similar to here.
There were a lot of great questions and answers about SPARQL and related technologies.

The website got sold two times, and since a few weeks, it has been down.
QUESTION: Is there a place where I can download a dump of the questions and answers?

The content had been made CC-BY-SA 3.0:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20151031172423/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/366/who-owns-the-content-on-this-site
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160306114803/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/21999/creative-commons-by-sa-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: Great point. However, I think this question belong to the meta forum.

Comment: @magdmartin: This is an open data request, so on-topic here I believe :-) Anyway I agree a meta question is mandated too, so I just wrote it: http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/358/answers-semanticweb-com-is-dead-should-we-do-something-about-it

Comment: Parse the latest [13 Feb 2016 snapshot at the WaybackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160213041555/http://answers.semanticweb.com/)? Even the link to the 185th (last) page works, bringing us back to 27 Oct 2009. The RSS link there does not do much (limited to 30 items)

Comment: anyone gotten started on this?

Comment: deleted my answer and am posting to meta.

Comment: I created a json-dump of the data -> see my [post at "open data meta" forum](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/a/366/14487)

Comment: @SeDav: Once you have extracted all data and uploaded it somewhere, please give the link as an answer here, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: As described in my question there (the second one you linked, [Creative Commons BY-SA for questions and answers?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306114803/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/21999/creative-commons-by-sa-for-questions-and-answers)), a part of the content was not openly licensed (namely, everything created after the owner decided to no longer use CC BY-SA).

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @SeDav Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

There is a dump available from the wayback machine, and user SeDav has written and made available a ...

> A script, that transforms questions from answers.semanticweb.com to a JSON file for possible migration

https://github.com/bastiion/answers.semanticweb.com-dump

> In order to download a copy of the site from the wayback machine you can use the ruby program wayback-machine-downloader (https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader).

---

here's the information from the meta post 
 - https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/a/366/1511